# Does processes quit when user logs off?

Tags: windows

In windows (in general), does process owned by a particular user exits when the corresponding user logs off (but computer is still on?)

Is the behavior consistent accross Windows / Windows Server ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a process initiated by the user (or by the system on behalf of the user) is terminated when that user logs off. If they only "switch users" or "lock" the computer, the processes reaming running in memory, as normal (though they may lose priority in the queue to process initiated by or on behalf of other users concurrently logged in).

As far as I know, this behaviour is the same on Windows Server, though I imagine that it the priority queue is even more skewed in favour of system processes when a user is not actively logged in.